# Need to match ALL similar words/phrases using preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, web, preg-match, preg-match-all

I'm trying to create a pattern that matches **all** similar words/phrases within a string.

For example, I need to match: "this", "this is", "this is it", "that", "that was", "that was not".

It only matches the first occurence of "this", but it should match **all** occurences.

I even tried anchors and word boundaries, but nothing seems to work.

I tried (simplified):

```
$content = "this is it! that was not!";

preg_match_all('/(this|this is|this is it|that|that was|that was not)/i', $content, $results);
```

Which should output:

- this
- this is
- this is it
- that
- that was
- that was not

Comment: Use `/(this( is( it)?)?)/`

Comment: Question: if you're only going to capture the substrings you're specifically searching for, why not settle for a `foreach` loop and `substr_count`?

Comment: @Mr. Llama Would you mind posting an example?

Comment: @Tom - Posted as an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26933945/477563

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you're only capturing the terms you're searching for, it might be better to simply use a `foreach` loop as well as `substr_count` to see how many times each string occurs.

For example:

```php
$haystack = "this is it! that was not! this is not a test!";
$needles = array(
    "this",
    "this is",
    "this is it",
    "that",
    "that was",
    "that was not");

foreach ($needles as $needle) {
    // substr_count is case sensitive, so make subject and search lowercase
    $hits = substr_count(strtolower($haystack), strtolower($needle));

    echo "Search '$needle' occurs $hits time(s)" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

The above will output:

```
Search 'this' occurs 2 time(s)
Search 'this is' occurs 2 time(s)
Search 'this is it' occurs 1 time(s)
Search 'that' occurs 1 time(s)
Search 'that was' occurs 1 time(s)
Search 'that was not' occurs 1 time(s)
```

If `substr_count` doesn't provide the flexibility that you need then you can always replace it with a `preg_match_all` and use your individual `$needle` values as search terms.

Comment: Thanks for posting an example. So, if I wanted to put all of the matches into an array, how would I do that? Sorry, I'm not the best PHP programmer.

Comment: The matches themselves wouldn't be of great consequence because you already know what they are (because you literally just searched for them).  If you want to store them though, you could do something like `for ($i = 0; $i < $hits; $i++) { $matches[] = $needle; }` just after the echo statement.

Comment: Thanks, that works. How would I remove duplicate matches from the array though? So, if "this is" is matched twice, it only stores it once in the array?

Comment: Would the array_unique function work? Or, is there something better?

Comment: @Tom - Just remove the `for` loop and make it `if ($hits > 0) { $matches[] = $needle; }`

Comment: When a match isn't found in the haystack, it shows an error message about substr_count being empty. Is there a way to fix this? Should the if statement have some sort of an else statement?

Comment: Nevermind my last question. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$content = "this is it";
preg_match_all('/(?=(this))(?=(this is))(?=(this is it))/i', $content, $results);
print_r($results);
```

**Edit according to comments:**

```
$content = "this is it";
preg_match_all('/(?=(this))(?=(this is))(?=(this is it))|(?=(that))(?=(that was))(?=(that was not))/i', $content, $results);
print_r($results);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => this
            [1] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => this is
            [1] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => this is it
            [1] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => that
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => that was
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => that was not
        )

)
```

More universal:

```
$content = "this is it! that was not!";
preg_match_all('/\b(?=(\w+))(?=(\w+ \w+))(?=(\w+ \w+ \w+))\b/i', $content, $results);
print_r($results);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => this
            [1] => that
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => this is
            [1] => that was
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => this is it
            [1] => that was not
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works well, but is there a way to add more words to the pattern that don't start with "this"? For example, it also matches something different (in addition to the above): "red", "red apple", "red apple tree"?

Comment: @Tom: Sorry, I don't get you. You may want to edit your question and give some sample strings and expected result.

Comment: No, it needs to match those exact words/phrases. Your first example works great, I just need to add more possible matches to the pattern.

Comment: Thanks! That works great! The only problem, is that if the string only contains a partial word/phrase - it doesn't match it. For example, if the string only contains "that was", it doesnt match anything. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the *shortest* string option appears first in your *or group*:

```
/(this|this is|this is it)/i
```

PHP will check if the test string contains a item of `(this|this is|this is it)` **from left to right**. Once it found a match in the test string it will leave the group.

This will work because PHP will search for the longest string first:

```
/(this is it|this is|this)/i
```

[Demo](http://regexr.com/39tg8)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, but it still doesn't show all possible results in the array. Any ideas?

Comment: Ah, I think I understand why it's only showing "this is it" in the array. The test string that I'm using only contains "this is it", whereas your test string has each word/phrase. Is there a way to get all matches with only "this is it"?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following regex instead.

```
/(this(?:\sis(?:\sit)?)?)/i
```

Comment: But that does not answer the question at all.